# Error while updating multi value User Profile Properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, user-profile

I am using [Bulk Import](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/bulk-user-profile-update-api-for-sharepoint-online) to update the multi-value user profile property.

I am getting the below error.

> Property Names [TestLocation] are Taxonomic Properties

The code works fine if I use any OOTB / custom single value property.

How can I resolve this error? Is there any configuration we need to do?

Thanks in advance.